# Use sed to remove anything not of the form 'ABCD'

Tags: sed

I have a csv file where some of the elements were garbled in transmission.  A valid identifier is exactly four uppercase letters, e.g., `KFIG`.  Occasionally I am getting an identifier such as `a~K%` or some other such nonsense.  How can I use `sed` to remove those cases?

I tried `sed 's/[^A-Z]*//g'` but this would still leave me with, for example, the single `K` in the garbled example I gave.  How can I apply the command to exactly four letters?

For example, here is a subset of what I have in the file:

```
)---
*TAR
+FHU
+FWA
+RQE
0KJS
ENOL
ENOV
```

The only two valid identifiers above are `ENOL` and `ENOV`.  I just want to delete the others.

Comment: Can you include some example lines?  Currently your sed command operates on the whole line, which probably isn't intentional.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete **lines** containing wrong identifiers, use:

```
sed -n '/[A-Z]\{4,\}/p'
```

Explanation:

- `sed` normally prints every line after evaluating all the expressions. `-n` option suppresses this behavior, so we have to explicitly print the line (with the `p` instruction);
- `\{4,\}` means "previous atom occurs four or more times", previous atom being `[A-Z]`;
- so the whole command means "print only those lines which contain four or more consecutive large letters".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and especially for explaining -n and p.  It worked just right.